# Angular 2: How to GET service response data from API to the Select Option

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Api.services.ts

```
 listNama() {
     return this.http.get(this.BaseURL + 'welcome/getnama')
            .pipe(map(response => {
                 return response;
            }));
 }
```

and I get The response like this

```
{
"status": "OK",
"Output": [
    {
        "id_pemborong": "1569079912",
        "nama": "ayub"
    },
    {
        "id_pemborong": "1569125109",
        "nama": "Hartono"
    },
    {
        "id_pemborong": "1569319859",
        "nama": "agus"
    },
    {
        "id_pemborong": "1569416787",
        "nama": "joko"
    }
   ]
 }
```

how can i bind this response to Select Option in angular. Help

Comment: what is the use of pipe here...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

service

```
listNama() {
    return this.http.get(this.BaseURL + 'welcome/getnama')
}
```

then subscribe it in your component

```
/decalre a variable
NameList:any[]=[];

/ replace service with your servicename
this.service.function.subscribe(arg => this.NameList = arg);
```

and in Template

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="selected" (change)="onChange($event)">
<option [label] ="nama" *ngFor="let item of NameList" [selected]="selected" 
  [value]="nama">{{nama}}
</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ts

```js
    NameList:any[]=[];
    listNama() {
    return this.http.get(this.BaseURL + 'welcome/getnama')
      .pipe(map(response => {
      this.NameList= response.Output;
      }));
     }
```

Html

```html
    <select  [(ngModel)]="selected" (change)="onChange($event)">
       <option [label] ="nama" *ngFor="let item of NameList" [selected]="selected" [value]="nama">
          {{nama}}
       </option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `map` is not doing anything. You need to instead `map` it to `Output` in your `response` and then subscribe to the Observable to get the value.

**api.service.ts**

```js
listNama() {
    return this.http.get(this.BaseURL + 'welcome/getnama').pipe(
        map(response => response.Output)
    );
}
```

Then subscribe to it in your component like so

```js
import ApiService from 'path/to/api/service';
...

    namaList: Nama[];

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.listNama().subscribe(data => {
            this.namaList = data;
        });
    }
```

where the `Nama` interface will look like this

```js
export interface Nama = {
    id_pemborong: string;
    nama: string;
}
```

Then use `namaList` in your template to display the list in the `select`.

```html
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let item of namaList" [value]="item.id_pemborong">{{item.nama}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why i got error in service from this.service.listNama() ?

Comment: Did you inject the service into your component?

Comment: i got it. sorry